# Cant customize the Verification code message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I’m helping a partner to customize their B2C policy to show a custom message for e-mail verification code. We tried to customize the following parameter on the **TrustFrameworkExtension** (Attached) but it had no effect:

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement"
StringId="ver_info_msg">Verification code has been sent to your inbox.
Please copy it to the input box below.</LocalizedString>\\
```

What we need to change is the display message for verification code, as shown on the image below:

[image]

Could anyone provide some guidance? I tried it different ways and I don´t know If we´re doing something wrong or if it´s a default message that can´t be customized. It´s impacting the partner go-live.

Comment: I guess you are looking for the solution to convert the content from english to different language (custom message). Am I right ?

Comment: Not really, we´re able to change the language of the message, but we were not able to change the content of the message. For example, the message says: "verification code sent to your inbox" and we want to change it "Please check your inbox for verification code"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization  - This will help you for sure

Comment: This is the same doc we have been following, we are trying the customization UxElement and as I said it has no effect

Answer (score 1):

thanks for guidance! the message we were trying to customize has a different StringID. The correct StringID is **verification_control_code_sent**

Once we fixed it we resolved the issue:

```
<!--Local account sign-up page Portuguese-->
      <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.pt">
        <LocalizedStrings>
          <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="verification_control_code_sent">Um código de segurança foi enviado para seu e-mail. Mantenha esta janela aberta.</LocalizedString>
```

Comment: just for clarity, here are listed all the strings used in localization: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids

Answer (score 0):

The [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-user-interface-elements) shows:

> The following are the IDs for a content definition with an ID of
> `api.localaccountsignup` or any content definition that starts with
> `api.selfasserted`, such as `api.selfasserted.profileupdate` and
> `api.localaccountpasswordreset`.

So you need to make the change in the appropriate “api.xxx” action.

The [sample](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/customising-the-message-error-text-in-azure-ad-b2c-custom-policies-d1e1ff2640d3) extends `Id` *api.localaccountsignup* to *api.localaccountsignup.en*. And change the value of `LocalizedString`.

```
<Localization Enabled="true">
  <SupportedLanguages DefaultLanguage="en" MergeBehavior="ReplaceAll">
    <SupportedLanguage>en</SupportedLanguage>
  </SupportedLanguages>
  <LocalizedResources Id="api.localaccountsignup.en">
    <LocalizedStrings>
      <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="ver_fail_no_retry">Attempt limit exceeded - please check your email for the correct code</LocalizedString>
    </LocalizedStrings>
  </LocalizedResources>
</Localization>
```

Then you need to change value of **ver_info_msg** in JSON defaults for built-in policies. For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-language-customization#change-extension-attributes).

Navigate to Azure AD B2C -> User flows -> Languages(make sure Enable language customization) -> Configured

[image]

[image]