# Unable to translate "Verification code has been sent. Please copy it to the input box below." message

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm unable to translate the text "Verification code has been sent. Please copy it to the input box below." on my Sing up page using Azure AD B2C.

I tried the solution on [Cant customize the Verification code message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267891/cant-customize-the-verification-code-message), but it didn't work for me. I was able to translate all the other texts on the page, but not this one.

I tried doing the following with no success:

```
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <LoadUri>~/tenant/templates/AzureBlue/selfAsserted.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.1</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Local account Signup</Item>
        </Metadata>
        <LocalizedResourcesReferences MergeBehavior="Prepend">
          <LocalizedResourcesReference Language="pt" LocalizedResourcesReferenceId="localaccountsignup.pt" />
        </LocalizedResourcesReferences>
      </ContentDefinition>
...
      <LocalizedResources Id="localaccountsignup.pt">
        <LocalizedStrings>
            <LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="verification_control_code_sent">Test.</LocalizedString>
...
```

When I try inserting the code above, I get the error:

> Validation failed: 1 validation error(s) found in policy
> "B2C_1A_PHONE_EMAIL_BASE" of tenant "MYWEBSITE.com".The
> localized string with ElementType: UxElement and StringId:
> verification_control_code_sent has an invalid StringIdThe localized
> string with ElementType: UxElement and StringId:
> verification_control_code_sent has an invalid StringId

[image: Message]

I tried a lot of other things too, with no success.

Comment: What is your `<DataUri>` version? See if this [answer](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/53589#issuecomment-709058017) helpful.

Comment: I had this same issue with: urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.1.1
The documentation does not refer to that particular message as deprecated, but it still is showing up for me. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#verification-display-control-user-interface-elements-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

I ended up getting this to work by changing the localization string to have the ElementType of a DisplayControl.

```
<LocalizedResources Id="localaccountsignup.pt">
  <LocalizedStrings>
    <LocalizedString ElementType="DisplayControl" ElementId="NAME_OF_YOUR_PHONE_CONTROL" StringId="success_send_code_msg">   </LocalizedString>
  </LocalizedStrings>
</LocalizedResources>
```

I found the code by looking in the attribute in the web console:
[image]

Made an issue on github about this: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/70611

Answer (score 0):

Thanks and Please try and let us know if you need more information.

urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0

and add "contract" into all content definition dataURIs like this, only selfasserted needs to be 2.0.0
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/contentdefinitions#migrating-to-page-layout

and then follow this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples#add-the-scriptexecution-element